# Should I stay with nextcord or should I come back to discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, nextcord

After discord.py got discontinued, I switched to nextcord to continue developing my bot, but with buttons and slash commands. But recently it was announced that discord.py is coming back. I have some experience with both of these libraries, and I wonder if it would be better to come back to discord.py.

Answer (score 3):

Nextcord was forked from discord.py, this is why the logo for Nextcord literally has a fork in it.  Because of this, the two remain very similar, and it's actually fairly trivial to port between them.  Both repos are very active on Github currently, and I can't think of any particularly cool feature that one has that the other doesn't to really warrant switching if you're already using one or the other.

I chose to stay with Nextcord instead of switching back to discord.py because after Rapptz wrote [an extremely longwinded post](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1) about why he was abandoning discord.py in the first place for what essentially amounted to a personality conflict with the Discord API team, I'm not too inclined to switch back to his repo now that he's changed his mind - I would rather stick with a community maintained fork.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already ported over, I recommend you to stay with that library.